# Why is "jump" between two primes (almost) always prime or 1 up to 1000?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

While looking at prime numbers between 1 to 1000 I noticed that the number of non-primes between prime numbers are almost always also prime or 1. In other words, if we take the prime gap,
$$
g_n=p_{n+1}-p_n,
$$
for prime numbers larger than 2, and subtract 1 from it, we almost always get a prime number or 1. In the cases (between 1 to 1000) where $g_n-1$ is not equal to a prime number or 1 it is instead equal to 9. Below is a figure I made to better explain:

[image]

What is the reason that the "jump length" (i.e. numbers in red or blue above) between primes are either 1, 9 or also prime when looking at 1 to 1000?

Comment: Because the gap between consecutive primes is always an even number, except for $3-2=1$

Comment: Is it just a coincidence that 15 never appears as a "jump length"?

Comment: It does,  $p_{282}=1831, p_{283}=1847$ and then again almost immediately, $p_{295}=1933,p_{296}=1949$.

Comment: General note:  it's tempting, but risky, to read too much into numerical computations for such small numbers.  In this case, there are many small primes, so any random-y list of small odd numbers is going to contain lots of primes.  To study anything like this, I'd want to look at much larger primes.

Comment: You can assume [Cramer's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%27s_conjecture): $g_n \approx O\left((\log{p_n})^2\right)$ and draw one or two conclusions, like $\left((\log(1000))^2\right)\approx 48$, consider only even gaps, that's $24$ and there are $14$ primes (or "jumps") between $1$ and $48$ (excluding $2$), thus the chance is $\frac{14}{24}=\frac{7}{12}>\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Absolutely agree with @lulu on this one. "Law of small numbers." A cursory look at http://oeis.org/A046933 seems to confirm your hypothesis. But look at the "b-file": it's still mostly primes, but 9, 15, 25 make more appearances the further along you go.

Comment: these are super insightful comments! So if I understand correctly; because primes > 2 are always uneven, their prime gap is always even and prime gap - 1 is thus always uneven, and when looking at *small* numbers almost all (except 9 and 15) uneven numbers are (incidentally) primes or 1 because the prime gap is still too small?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This phenomenon was studied by Odlyzko, Rubinstein and Wolf (with whom I have written a paper on primes).

> **Definition**: An integer $d$ is called a jumping champion for a given $x$ if d is the most common gap between consecutive primes up to $x$.

They postulated that most common gap between primes or the jumping champions are the product of prime numbers i.e. the first jumping champion is $2$. The after some time, $2*3 = 6$ takes over as the next jumping champion. At around $1.74*10^{35}$, the number $2*3*5 = 30$ takes over as the next jumping champion. At around $10^{425}$, the number $2*3*5*7 = 210$ takes over as the next jumping champion and so on.

This means that per your definitions, if we subtract $1$ from the gap between primes then the most common results would be $1$ initially. This would be overtaken by $5$ which would in turn be overtaken by $29$ and this would be overtaken by $209$ as you go higher up the number line.

So it is a co-incidence that $5, 29$ are prime but $209 = 11*19$ is not. This means if you looked large enough to reach the range of $209$, you would actually have the ***opposite conclusion*** based on experimental evidence that gap between prime minus $1$ is often a non prime.

**Equivalent question**: With the above arguments, your question is equivalent to

> How often is the primorial number $2.3.5.7\cdots p - 1$ a prime?

**Reference:**

1. Odlyzko, A.; Rubinstein, M.; and Wolf, M. "Jumping Champions."
   Experiment. Math. 8, 107-118, 1999.

Comment: Nice answer! Do you know whether any result of this form (classifying jumping champions) has been proven, or if it's all just conjecture so far?

Comment: As with most problems with primes, we have way more conjectures on jumping champions than theorems. However you can find a few theorems on them by Goldston in this paper. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1102.4879.pdf